# No Sound through Chrome Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: sound, 14.10

So I've just installed Ubuntu 14.1 on my laptop. Sound Won't play through Chrome, but will happily play normally through system sounds and Firefox. Sound settings don't even detect chrome as an application that is playing something. I've gone through a fair amount of similar posts on the same issues but for older distro's, none of which have been able to solve my problem. Any ideas on what is going wrong with chrome and my sound software/hardware? Thanks for any help.